# Flutter gesture bar - invisible tile content

Tags: ios, flutter, state, gesture

I am having this phenomena with the gesture bar on the ios simulator.

The content inside the tile is cut out but the tile itself is visible.
Anyone an idea why?

Of corse, I want the content to be seen as well.

[image]